# Output the cursor's position in a Textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a textfield controller in Flutter and wish to return the position which the cursor occupies in the textfield?

Keep in mind a user may have typed in text then moved the cursor back along the text to say edit the text.

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (value) {
    //TODO - Return Cursor Position
  }
),
```

Comment: write all your code in your questions

Comment: @RahmanRezaee - i've added the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the cursor posistion in text field
first make controller for text field now

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (value) {
    int cursorPos = _textController.selection.base.offset;
    print(cursorPos);
    //TODO - Return Cursor Position
  }
),
```